# MongoDB Get Single Object Nested in Array of Objects in Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, javascript-objects

How do you access a single object nested in an array of objects that is nested in another array of objects, based on a few property values, something like this in pseudo code:

**SELECT DAY=1 WHERE _id=5a3469f22dc3784bdd9a6190 AND MONTH=12**

Mongoose model schema is listed below. As required, subdocuments are listed higher than their corresponding parents, dailySchedulesSchema being the highest:

```
var dailySchedulesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    day: Number,
    dayStart: Number,
    firstBreakStart: Number,
    firstBreakEnd: Number,
    lunchStart: Number,
    lunchEnd: Number,
    secondBreakStart: Number,
    secondBreakEnd: Number,
    dayEnd: Number,
    workDuration: Number
});

var monthlyScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    month: {type: Number, required: true },
    dailySchedules: [dailySchedulesSchema]
});

var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    surname: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    occupation: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type: Boolean, required: true},
    monthlySchedule: [monthlyScheduleSchema]
});
```

This is the employee entry in the database I am trying to work on.:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3469f22dc3784bdd9a6190"),
        "name" : "Eric",
        "surname" : "K. Farrell",
        "email" : "EricKFarrell@dayrep.com",
        "phone" : "864-506-7281",
        "occupation" : "Employee",
        "status" : true,
        "monthlySchedule" : [
                {
                        "month" : 12,
                        "dailySchedules" : [
                                {
                                        "day" : 1,
                                        "dayStart" : 480,
                                        "firstBreakStart" : 600,
                                        "firstBreakEnd" : 615,
                                        "lunchStart" : 720,
                                        "lunchEnd" : 750,
                                        "secondBreakStart" : 870,
                                        "secondBreakEnd" : 885,
                                        "dayEnd" : 1020,
                                        "workDuration" : 480
                                },
                                {
                                        "day" : 2,
                                        "dayStart" : 540,
                                        "firstBreakStart" : 630,
                                        "firstBreakEnd" : 645,
                                        "lunchStart" : 750,
                                        "lunchEnd" : 780,
                                        "secondBreakStart" : 870,
                                        "secondBreakEnd" : 885,
                                        "dayEnd" : 1050,
                                        "workDuration" : 480
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The route itself for getting single day is:  **"/employees/:employeeid/:month/:day"** .

While I managed to access the parent documents(like listing all employees), I was unable to list specific subdocument entries(like specific day schedule for that employee) - mongoose has either been returning all of the existing day schedules in the month or nothing at all:

(...)

```
  var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content){
        res.status(status);
        res.json(content);
    }
```

(...)

```
module.exports.empDayReadOne = function(req, res){
    var monthParam = req.params.month;
    var employeeid = req.params.employeeid;
    var dayParam = req.params.day;

    Emp
        .aggregate([
        {$match: {$and: [{'monthlySchedule': {$elemMatch: {$exists: true} } }, {_id: employeeid }] } },
        {$unwind:'$monthlySchedule'}, 
        {$unwind:'$monthlySchedule.dailySchedules'}, 
        {$match:{ $and:[ {'monthlySchedule.dailySchedules.day': dayParam},{'monthlySchedule.month': monthParam} ] } }

        ])
        .exec(function(err, dailySchedule){
            if(dailySchedule){
                sendJsonResponse(res, 200, dailySchedule);
            } else if(err){
                sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
                return;
            } else {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "This day has no schedules added."});
                return;
            }

        });

};
```

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: I am using version 3.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

The below query first [`$filters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filters/) `monthlySchedule` which returns the array with the matching month array element followed by second filter to retrieve the matching day element in `dailySchedules` array.

[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to convert the array with single element into a document.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"_id":ObjectId("5a3469f22dc3784bdd9a6190")}},
  {"$project":{
    "dailyschedule":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
        {"$filter":{
          "input":{
            "$filter":{
              "input":"$monthlySchedule",
              "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.month",12]}
            }
          },
          "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.day",1]
          }
        }},
      0]
    }
  }}
])
```

Updated Mongoose code:

```
Emp.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"_id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employeeid)}},
  {"$project":{
    "dailyschedule":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
        {"$filter":{
          "input":{
            "$filter":{
              "input":"$monthlySchedule",
              "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.month",monthParam]}
            }
          },
          "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.day",dayParam]
          }
        }},
      0]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: But with $arrayElemAt you need to know the value's index in the array, whereas the example above does not seem to regard that and simply cares for the specific key values which it searches for. Looks like a more practical example, to be honest.

Comment: $arrayElemAt with index 0 is used to convert the matching day schedule ( one match ) to a document.Without arrayElemAt you will end up the array with matching day schedule in it. You can remove the arrayElemAt if you like. $unwind precisely does what I did with arrayElemAt as it will always output one daily schedule match. So $unwind is not required here.

Comment: findOne method seems to do the job well, apart from returning the whole dailySchedules array. Is there a way for it to suppress the rest of the indexes?

Emp.findOne(
            {_id: employeeid, "monthlySchedule.month":monthParam, "monthlySchedule.dailySchedules.day": dayParam}
        )

Comment: That is why we use aggregation as that cant be done using regular query language. Is the aggregation code not working for you ? Its pretty straightforward you first filter the monthlySchedule array based on month param followed by filtering daySchedule  array on day param. If you insist it doing in find query then best you can do is ouput the monthy schedule array based on monthly param from server and do client side filterting of day schedule on day param. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This certainly works through mongoose: Emp.aggregate([
        {$match: {"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employeeid)}},
        {$unwind:'$monthlySchedule'}, 
        {$unwind:'$monthlySchedule.dailySchedules'}, 
        {$match:{ $and:[ {'monthlySchedule.month': 12}, {'monthlySchedule.dailySchedules.day': 1} ] } }
        ])   , except for monthParam and dayParam, which I have hardcoded. How to represent them in the aggregate method?

Comment: Try  `var monthParam = Number.parseInt(req.params.month)` and pass it to aggregate methods. No $unwind is needed as shown in my answer.